# Tower Defense Problem

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, collision-detection, collision

I am creating a tower defense game and I want to make a tower that shoots a bullet and every enemy that the bullet hits is damaged. The bullet can hurt multiple units. My problem is detecting if the bullet hits the enemies.

Right now, I have the enemies in an array. With other towers, when an enemy is in range, the tower fires and when it hits its original target, it causes damage to that target.

For the tower I want to make, it will shoot the bullet the maximum range every time and I need it to damage every unit it hits on the way to that final destination.

Anyone have any ideas on how best to do this? I been thinking it through for a while and haven't come up with anything useful.

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place to ask this.

Comment: I agree that gamedev is probably a better place for this...  Just curious, how are you doing the collision detection for a single hit?  I would think you could just extend this and allow the "bullet" to travel beyond just the first enemy and hit more things.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know there was a gamedev.stackexchange, I will ask there too. For the other towers, I tell the bullet where to go and I use a hitTestPoint() function.

For this tower, I am using a hitTestObject() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the challenge identifying where to aim the turret, or how to identify whether the targets on the line are struck?

For a example, a simple way to create the line might be: Turret targets first enemy in range, draw a line extending from turret through that enemy for the length of the turret range.  In that case, the problem comes down to determining whether the current enemies are within acceptable range of the line.

If your problem is instead how to draw the line, perhaps you could clarify what part of the problem is an issue in particular.

Comment: Actually, I just did something similar. Once the bullet reaches its max range, I draw a line from that point back to where the bullet originated.

Next, I loop through the enemy array use hitTestObject on each one with the line I created. If there is a hit, it damages the enemy. 

It's not perfect, I would like something more realtime that damages the enemy as it hits it but so far this is the best I could come up with.

Sometimes it seems like enemies are getting hit that aren't actually touching the line.

Comment: When bullet reaches max range, its too late to draw line, you should do it when it still flies continuosly.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to create a bullet object on the fire event. There are several things a bullet needs to keep track of.

- velocity
- distance traveled
- enemy hit

Move the bullet by its velocity each frame. Check if the distance is greater than the tower's maximum range. If it is, destroy it. Only create a collision event with enemies if the enemy has not been hit yet.

Answer (score 0):

This question is very vague.

In general you want to :

create a bullet

each frame update it's location

check if it has hit the max distance from tower, if so kill the bullet

check if bullet has hit an enemy in your array

if an enemy is hit trigger an explosion or some kind of visual cue and or sound effect, and apply damage etc.

--only allow it to hit the enemy once - you can do this by tracking it in the bullet. -- ie have an array of enemies it has hit.

Do you understand how to code each of these items ?

Comment: Yes, my main problem has been how to flag if the enemies were hit. I think I will try to store them in an array if they are hit like you said.

Comment: yes, it's important to do it in the bullet as multiple bullets can hit the same enemy i am assuming. So you want to know which enemies that bullet has hit.

Answer (score 0):

Use hittestpoint method.

```
if(enemy.hitTestPoint(bullet.x,buttet.y) {
  dosomething()
}
```

for the array:

```
for (var i:int = 0;i<enemyArray.lenght;i++) 
if(enemyArray[i].hitTestPoint(bullet.x,buttet.y) {
  dosomething()
}
```